# Getting price of Dollar in INR

Tags: java, jsp

I have an application where I have some prices in Dollars and some in INR. Now when I show price of a commodity, Depending on its price is in Dollars or INR, I can tell the currency I am showing the price in. The problem comes when I am showing the total or Net-Worth. In that case, I have to convert either INR to Dollar or Vice-Versa. Can anyone help me with obtaining price of dollar in INR, using java.

Comment: Is your goal to get real-time data on the current exchange rate?

Comment: `curl 'http://www.google.com/search?q=100+USD+in+INR'`

Comment: @thilo: I knw the url but dnt knw how to use it. When I use finance.yahoo.com it returns a csv file, wat kind of thing this url returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use exchange rate APIs available [here](http://www.exchangerate-api.com/howto). I am not sure how reliable or up to date the service is.

Comment: Thanks Suresh it works. Though there is a marginal diff b/w original value and value return by it(.20 Rs).